# Uploading Multiple Images in React and Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, react-redux, material-ui

I'm trying to upload multiple images and I'm passing the image one by one to the API so once an image will be uploaded, it can already be displayed without waiting for other images to finish uploading.

My problem is I have a loader and I display it when images are uploading. If some images are already finished uploading while other are still uploading, the loader disappears already?

**Component**

```
{
  isImagesUploading && (
    <Box sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <LinearProgress />
    </Box>
  );
}



const onUploadImage = (files) => {
  const fileList = Array.from(files);
  const images = fileList.map((image) => {
    ...
  });

  uploadImages(newImages);
};
```

**Reducer**

```
case UPLOAD_IMAGES_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        isImagesUploading: true,
      }
case UPLOAD_IMAGES_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        isImagesUploading: false,
        images: action.payload
      }
```

**Action**

```
export const uploadImages =
  ({ images }) =>
  async (dispatch) => {
    images.forEach(async (image) => {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append(image.name, image.imageFile);

      try {
        dispatch({
          type: UPLOAD_IMAGES_REQUEST,
        });

        const response = await axios.post("http://test.com", formData);

        dispatch({
          type: UPLOAD_IMAGES_SUCCESS,
          payload: [...(images || [])],
        });
      } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
          type: UPLOAD_IMAGES_FAILURE,
        });
      }
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could track a count of pending uploads. Any count > 0 show any loading indicator in your UI.

Example:

```
case UPLOAD_IMAGES_REQUEST:
  return {
    ...state,
    imageUploadCount: state.imageUploadCount + 1,

case UPLOAD_IMAGES_REQUEST:
  return {
    ...state,
    imageUploadCount: state.imageUploadCount - 1,
    images: action.payload
  };

case UPLOAD_IMAGES_FAILURE:
  return {
    ...state,
    imageUploadCount: state.imageUploadCount - 1,
  };
```

...

```
export const uploadImages = ({ images }) => (dispatch) => {
  images.forEach(async (image) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(image.name, image.imageFile);

    try {
      dispatch({ type: UPLOAD_IMAGES_REQUEST });

      const response = await axios.post("http://test.com", formData);

      dispatch({
        type: UPLOAD_IMAGES_SUCCESS,
        payload: [...(images || [])],
      });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({ type: UPLOAD_IMAGES_FAILURE });
    }
  });
};
```

In your ui, create a state selector function to read the count and derive if any loading indicator should be displayed.

Example:

```
const isUploading = useSelector(state => state.images.imageUploadCount > 0);

...

return (
  <>
    {isUploading && <LoadingSpinner />}
    ...
  </>
);
```

Comment: @Joseph Do you mean something like 6/10 processed image uploads converted to a percent? If you know the total when starting you could start with *that* count and decrement after each processed image. This would allow you to derive both that images are actively uploading and the total that have completed.

Comment: @Joseph It seems like you've a good grasp on the individual file upload progress status/value and this seems little off-topic from the initial issue of the loader intermittently rendering. Again, if you know the total number of files being uploaded then you know the total percent. Use the `dispatch(setUploadProgress(percentage))` to "fill the jar" from 0 to 100 * uploads.

Comment: @Joseph Hmm, right.... the outer one seems superfluous since nothing is asynchronous to `await` in that function body.

Comment: Hi Drew. Can you help me on my latest question? Thank you.